# How to create a multidimensional array with variable length

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'd like to create a matrix (same height and width) with a variable size, meaning that height and width depend on a variable. Now I know how to reserve store with malloc/calloc, but I can't figure out how to use malloc to create a two-dimensional array.
Or is there a different way to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do a search. This is answered many many times on Stackoverflow and else where.

Comment: There's two typical solutions. The first is to allocate a single contiguous chunk of memory that can then be accessed as if it is a 2D matrix with careful indexing. The second is to allocate an pointer to `double *` (aka `double **`), and then allocate each of those rows one by one. Search this site for a few seconds, and I'm sure you'll find lots of examples of each.

Comment: `int (*m)[cols] = malloc( sizeof(int[rows][cols]) );`

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to use malloc to create a two-dimensional array.

```
// Example of a 2D array.  malloc() cannot create this.
int TwoD[height][width];
```

`malloc()` can allocate memory *for* an `int`, an array, etc.  It can not create an array.  The result of `malloc()` is a pointer.  So start with a *pointer* to a 2D array.

```
// C99, C11
int (*a)[height][width];
```

Allocate memory for `a`

```
a = malloc(sizeof *a); 
assert(a); // Insure NULL was not retuned.
```

Use the memory

```
(*a)[0][0] = 1;
(*a)[0][1] = 2;
// ... 
(*a)[height-1][width-1] = height*width;
```

Free when done

```
free(a);
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I think I have a different problem: In my for-loop that basically copies a matrix to the new allocated memory, I get the error that my counter variable j has to have the type "pointer-to-object". I've searched the web but couldn't really find a helpful answer.

_for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {_
 _for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {_
  _*newgen[i][j] = oldgen[i][j];_
 _}_
_}_

Comment: @MrCGenius What difference do you see between this answer's sample code `(*a)[0][0]` and your code `*newgen[i][j]`?